# How do I check for the null value in Java?

Tags: java

How to look for the value whether it is null or not in JSP. E.g. in below I want to check the description column in pipe table for null values.

```
String Query1 = "SELECT description FROM pipe where pipe_id='" + id+"' and version_id=2";
SQLResult = SQLStatement.executeQuery(Query1);
SQLResult.first();
description = SQLResult.getString("description");
if(description=="")
{
    json_string=json_string+"&desc="+description;
    out.println("not null");
} else
{
    json_string=json_string;
    out.println("null");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To format blocks of code here, just indent by 4 spaces. No need for `<pre>` or `<code>` tags.

Comment: *beep* SQL injection alert. Note: writing Java code incorrectly inside a JSP file instead of a real Java class and having basic Java problems with it doesn't make it a JSP problem. So I removed the JSP tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well: `if (description != null && !description.isEmpty())` ... however are you writing this code within a JSP ? That seems wrong. You should probably do this stuff within a servlet and pass the description as an request attribute to a jsp.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use [`StringUtils.isNotEmpty(description)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are really using jsp, you should store description in a request attribute and then use `<c:if test="${empty description}">`.

Answer (score 1):

I use this personal method:

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null || obj.toString().length() < 1 || obj.toString().equals(""))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```